# Manipulate String In XSL

Tags: xslt, string, char, character

I have a string variable in xsl - I want to be able to get the first character in that string. Is there a sort of "cut" method that I can use to retrieve this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <xsl:value-of select="substring($string,1,1)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see the example usage of substring here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256054.aspx